# SQL Server database max row RowVersion

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Does anyone know if there is a way I can get a database's max RowVersion value? The database I am using is SQL Server 2008.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you looking from @@DBTS, which is the last used value?  The variable name still references the deprecated TIMESTAMP (TS part) data type but it's the ROWVERSION last value.

```
SELECT @@DBTS
```

Comment: Basicaly I want to check if a database has been changed since last  time. So I remember the RowVersion value I made a check last time, and compare it with current value.

Comment: Just note that it may be better to use [`MIN_ACTIVE_ROWVERSION()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb839514.aspx#Anchor_3) if any transactions are currently running.